# Change Coordinator Layout's layout above property

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout

how can i add or remove property of coordinator layout?
Such as this?

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want add or remove the layout_above property in base of value.
How can i do it?
Thanks

I've tried to put this code:

```
CoordinatorLayout layoutCoordinator = findViewById(R.id.tab_coordinator_layout);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

        layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) layoutCoordinatot.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.removeRule(/* code for layout ?? */);
```

But it is missing the remove and add rule function why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is missing the addRule and removeRule functions because these function are not a part of class CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams but of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

```
CoordinatorLayout tabCL = findViewById(R.id.tab_coordinator_layout);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) tabCL.getLayoutParams();

params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE);


tabCL.setLayoutParams(params);
```